# find the year when an event occurred of a panel data in R

Tags: r

have a question when dealing with a data frame constructed by a panel data,

```
firm<-c("1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","3","3","3","3")
year<-c("2001","2002","2003","2004","2005","1998","1999","2000","2004","2005","2006","2007")
event<-c("yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","no","yes","no","no","no")
df<-data.frame("firm"= firm,"year"= year, "event" = event)
```

what I want is something like :

```
firm<-c("1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","3","3","3","3")
year<-c("2001","2002","2003","2004","2005","1998","1999","2000","2004","2005","2006","2007")
event<-c("yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","no","yes","no","no","no")
event.year<-c("2004","2004","2004","2004","2004","2000","2000","2000","2005","2005","2005","2005")
df<-data.frame("firm"= firm,"year"= year, "event" = event,"event.year" = event.year)
```

question is how to generate the column "event.year"?

Answer (score 2):

```
firm<-c("1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","3","3","3","3")
year<-c("2001","2002","2003","2004","2005","1998","1999","2000","2004","2005","2006","2007")
event<-c("yes","yes","yes","no","no","yes","yes","no","yes","no","no","no")
df<-data.frame("firm"= firm,"year"= year, "event" = event)

library(plyr)
df1 = ddply(df, .(firm), mutate, event.year = year[which(event=="no")[1]])
```

Comment: Or use `match` i.e. `df %>% group_by(firm) %>% mutate(event.year = year[match('no', event)])`